# Lists (JSON): Do's & Don'ts

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-list, json-formatting, recommendations

My question is what are best practices and/or do's and dont's when programming JSON for SharePoint lists.
What are hints to keep a good performance when managing large lists with custom views?

Answer (score 0):

1.Per my knowledge, there are no Do's & Don'ts for JSON formatting. How to use JSON formatting depends on your specific requirement.

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

[Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

2.[Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)